# Upload file to OneDrive using RestAPI

Tags: c#, rest, onedrive, restsharp

I am trying to upload an image to OneDrive using below code. The file was successfully uploaded to the OneDrive folder but when I download the file manually from OneDrive, it opens in black color and shows Invalid Image.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + $"/drives/{driveID}/items/{folderId}:/{originalFileName}:/content");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", Path.GetExtension(originalFileName).GetMimeType());
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());
request.AddFile("content", System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), originalFileName);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I really do not know what mistake I am making in here. May you please help me?

Comment: `AddFile` appears to result in a multipart request, which isn't what the contract for `/content` requires. That endpoint needs the raw file bytes in a standalone request. At a glance I'm not sure how you do that with `RestRequest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39242097/3682161)

I need to change it to `HttpClient` from `RestClient`. After change the code will like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + $"/drives/{driveID}/items/{folderId}:/{originalFileName}:/content";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());

    byte[] sContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(sContents);

    var response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```